# Pandas: Is it possible to down-sample categorical column?

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data, pandas-resample

Let's have a DataFrame *log* such this one:

```
>>> log
                           state
date_time                       
2020-01-01 00:00:00            0
2020-01-01 00:01:00            0
2020-01-01 00:02:00            0
2020-01-01 00:03:00            1
2020-01-01 00:04:00            1
2020-01-01 00:05:00            1
```

where *state* column can be either 0 or 1 (or missing). If represented with UInt8 (smallest numeric datatype supporting <NA>) one can down-sample the data like this:

```
>>> log.resample(dt.timedelta(minutes=2)).mean()
                           state
date_time                       
2020-01-01 00:00:00          0.0
2020-01-01 00:02:00          0.5
2020-01-01 00:04:00          1.0
```

The resampling works just fine, only the value 0.5 make no sense, since it can be only 0 or 1. From the same reason, it make sense to use *category* as dtype for this column. However, in this case the resampling will not work as the *mean()* method is only applicable to numerical data.

This makes a perfect sense - however - I can imagine a down-sampling & averaging procedure on categirical data where, as long as the data in group stays identical, the result will be that particular value, otherwise the result will be <NA>, like:

```
categorical_average(['aple', 'aple']) -> 'aple'
categorical_average(['pear', 'pear']) -> 'pear'
categorical_average(['aple', 'pear']) -> <NA>
```

Which for presented DataFrame *log* with category *state* column would result in:

```
>>> log.resample(dt.timedelta(minutes=2)).probably_some_other_method()
                         state
date_time                       
2020-01-01 00:00:00          0
2020-01-01 00:02:00       <NA>
2020-01-01 00:04:00          1
```

BTW, I am doing `resample.main()` because there are many other (numerical) columns, where it make perfect sense, I just did not mentioned it explicitelly here for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom function for test if unique values with `if-else`:

```
f = lambda x: x.iat[0] if len(x) > len(set(x)) else pd.NA
a = log.resample(dt.timedelta(minutes=2)).agg({'state':f})
print (a)
                    state
date_time                
2020-01-01 00:00:00     0
2020-01-01 00:02:00  <NA>
2020-01-01 00:04:00     1
```

Comment: Thank you! Due to the consistency with other actually missing values I only changed pd.NA to np.nan (it looks like there is no NaN in pandas) as categorical data use NaN for missing vaues, while IntegerArray use NA...